# How to disable the gridStack auto position functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridstack

How to disable the grid stack default position behaviour. Whenever we try to drag the container downward, due to the auto position functionality, It automatically goes to the upward. I tried some examples mentioned in the GitHub like set 'float: true' in the gridStack options, but It is not working either.

Comment: can you add the code you tried and try creating a demo

Comment: @Allabakash No, Please share any idea if you have. I've already mentioned what I tried.

Comment: this might help you - https://github.com/kdietrich/gridstack-angular/blob/master/demo/bower_components/gridstack/doc/README.md#item-attributes